# Build Primefaces from Source

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good evening,

since a few weeks it's only possible to build Primefaces 5 from source. I wonder, is it possible to build a Version 4.07 from the Repository?

Comment: You should ask it on their forum.

Comment: What do you mean by " it's only possible to build Primefaces 5 from source" ? The sources for various versions are available under http://primefaces.org/downloads .

Comment: As is stated: not possible with the official releases without a paid plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it isn't possible to get the source of a specific version.

Comment: http://primefaces.org/downloads does not count?

Comment: I want to build from maven...also primefaces.org let you only download the maintenance releases if you haven't subscribed to a paid-plan.

Comment: You can't get the source of ELITE versions, but all the release versions are available.  https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/checkout   --  http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/ has the latest just go back a directory

Comment: Please read my question. I know the Maven repo...i was asking for an _easy_ way to build an specific version from that repo. you could not easily go back, cause you never know which revision is the specific primefaces build.